# iOS, icon is not visible when archiving for distribution

Tags: ios, icons, distribution, archive

The icon was not shown when archiving for distribution. though, it was shown when testing on a device.

I faced no errors, the process went smoothly and the app was uploaded successfully to the App store.

I keep reading question about (icon is not shown in archives) but I can't understand why such thing is important which lead me to my question.

So, the question is: Will the icon be shown when the users download the app? and if yes, why should I care if the icon is shown or not while archiving??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really care for that, it'll be shown to the users when downloaded from the app store